# Is there a standard code order in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, models

I was wondering if there was any type of convention on how code in models should be ordered.

For example...

```
Class Foobar
  #includes

  #associations

  #accepts_nested_attributes_for

  #validations

  etc...
end
```

Specifically I was looking for a default model template to replace the standard one.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not. At this point you have to use your own conventions and it is likely that the readability of your code won't be affected by such small differences (e.g. placing reflections before validations and vice versa for instance).